# How to set row color based on column condition in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

```
 protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Status");
            int msgid;

            int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MsgID")), out msgid);            
            string status = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MessageActive"));
        if(status.Equals("No"))
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
        } 
         //Based on some condition I am assigning images to the row
           if (value >= Toptarg)
            {
                img.ImageUrl = "Styles/Images/GreenBox.jpg";
                img.ToolTip = "Met Top Target";
                img.AlternateText = "Met Top Target";
            }
            else
            {
                img.ImageUrl = "Styles/Images/AmberBox.jpg";
                img.ToolTip = "In Progress";
                img.AlternateText = "In Progress";
            }

         }
      }
```

I have a gridView and it has a column named MessageActive, In the row databind I get the value of the messageActive. If the messageActive value is 'Yes' no changes are required. If it is 'No' I want to display the particular row in red color, How can I set the row background Color in row databound

Some properties of the grid view

```
   <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="MistyRose" />
   <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#696969" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
```

Namespace 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;

I am getting this error

```
 'Image' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' and 'System.Drawing.Image'

Source Error:


Line 56:         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
Line 57:         {
Line 58:             Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Status");
Line 59:             int msgid;
Line 60:             int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MsgID")), out msgid);
```

Comment: I solved my error by using   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.FindControl("Status");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string status = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MessageActive"));
if (status == "No")
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing it, Drawing does not exist in current context error. I included using System.Drawing; but still same error

Comment: @Mark: You probably need an additional reference to System.Drawing.Color in your project.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your method:

```
if(status.Equal("No"))
{
  e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red; // or Color.FromName("#FF0000");
}
```

as side note, I would manipulate the color or other styles in the `PreRender` event handler and not in the `RowDataBound`...

**Edit:** You should add the reference to the .NET assembly System.Drawing as by default it is not included in the ASP.NET web project templates...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line:

```
Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Status");
```

To explictily reference the image class you want so for example:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.FindControl("Status");
```

Or to the other class if you want to use that one.